# Better windows command line shells

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

Is there a better windows command line shell other than `cmd` which has better copy paste between Windows' windows and console windows?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Take Command](http://www.jpsoft.com/tcmddes.htm) does support Copy/Cut/Paste from the keyboard and the mouse.  It's pretty handy if you do a lot of work from a command prompt.  It also supports:

- Command and folder history, with popup windows to select prior commands or folders.
- Screen scroll back buffer
- Enhanced batch commands
- Built in FTP/HTTP file access
- A toolbar with programmable buttons

Note: It's a paid tool, with price of $99.95.

Comment: It is a paid tool ($99.95). It would be nice to make a note about this here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that TC also invents it's own scripting language this is pretty much worthless for any other environment. --- Powershell, especially when used in the Powershell ISE, is a better choice.

Comment: what about PowerShell??

Answer (score 58):

Enable **QuickEdit mode**, under the *Options*  tab of your shortcut to the command shell. Mark with the mouse, right-click to copy, right-click again to paste.

While you're there, enable a hotkey (like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>) for lightning fast access to the shell.

And no, you can't have  <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for **COPY**, because <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> means **BREAK**.

On a related note, the Microsoftee who changed the default setting of *QuickEdit mode* between Windows Server 2000 and 2003 is an idiot and I heap curses upon him each workday.

Comment: Quick edit mode used to be standard in w2k. One of the first things I do when "making my self at home" on a new computer.

Comment: If you use [clink](http://code.google.com/p/clink/) you can set up CTRL+SHIFT+V for paste and much more!

Comment: In Windows 7 (at least) you can also switch to _QuickEdit_ mode by right-clicking the title bar of your cmd/powershell window and selecting it under **properties** or you can make it the default by selecting it under **defaults**. This is particularly useful if you use Windows Explorer context menus to invoke your shells instead of a windows shortcut.

Answer (score 25):

Windows PowerShell is the obvious choice when it comes to "better windows command line shell other than cmd". Its clipboard handling isn't that much of an improvement - mark with the mouse, Enter to copy, or right mouse click to paste.

Comment: To be honest, clipboard handling is *exactly* the same as with any other console application as the console host handles that, not the application running in the console.

Comment: I honestly don't understand why MS has their head so firmly wedged on this. Just fix it, it's 2018. I was very disappointed when I installed the new linux subsystem stuff only to find the same crappy "terminal" window.

Answer (score 21):

This probably is not exactly what you want, but you can take a look at [Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/)

I have it configured so that shift+select auto copies and middle click pastes, really handy, internally it uses same old cmd.exe so you are not really getting a different shell.

By the way, I guess **<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>** = copy is not the best idea in a command line context because it usually means interrupt running process.

Comment: For Linux shells, Ctrl-Char commands (like copy) are usually replaced with Ctrl-Shift-Char

Comment: Console 2 was horribly buggy last time I looked.

Comment: +1 I found out about Console 2 from this post and have been using it extensively for the past 6 months. It's NOT a replacement for the  command. It is, in fact, a shell for shells that allows for configurability that is not present in either the Command shell or the standard PowerShell.

Comment: This is a console/terminal emulator, not a shell.

Comment: @nightcracker hence my comment "you are not really getting a different shell" still it solves his problem of getting better / more configurable copy paste support

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you're trying to do with the shell, [rxvt](http://www.google.com/search?q=rxvt+cygwin) in [cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is good.

You'll get the nicety of auto copy on selection and middle click paste.  The biggest downside is that some windows console apps don't play nice with cygwin.

Comment: If you're going for cygwin, puttycyg is a great choice: http://code.google.com/p/puttycyg/

Comment: Also **mintty**, is very nice with cygwin. (it's also available in the cygwin installation/setup)

Answer (score 3):

PowerCmd is cheaper than TakeCommand and has a lot of powerful features - not the least of which is better handling of Cut/Copy/Paste.  I've only been using it a short time but I'm really impressed so far:

Summary from the site:

> PowerCmd enhances your command prompt
>   with an easy-to-use Windows GUI-style
>   interface and allows you to run
>   multiple consoles within a single
>   tabbed window. You can easily organize
>   multiple consoles in vertical,
>   horizontal, and grid forms. Auto-log,
>   auto-completion, keywords highlight,
>   configurable font and colors,
>   customizable toolbar for frequently
>   used commands or tools and minimizing
>   to tray are easy solutions to daily
>   needs. With PowerCmd, you can save and
>   restore your sessions from last time.

Site:
http://www.powercmd.com/

Features:
http://www.powercmd.com/features.php

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what specifically you mean by *better copy/paste* but try [Take Command](http://www.jpsoft.com).

Take Command supports Shift+Ins for paste and Shift+Del for cut, but apparently nothing for copy, will dig some more.

Comment: You can configure Take Command to send one of the control keys to Take Command and the other to the running app.  You could use Left-Ctrl-C to copy to the clipboard and Right-CtrL-C to send the Ctrl-C cancel signal to the application.

Comment: Uh Take Command is $99!

Answer (score 2):

There are two portion to cmd.exe.  First there is the window that pops up for dealing with the text console.  I would replace that with [ConEmu](https://code.google.com/p/conemu-maximus5/).  That program is actually meant as a wrapper for the Far File manager but works just fine without it.  It is very similar to Console2 but also is much more stable and has better features.

Second there is the command line interpreter.  I would replace that with [Powershell](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978526.aspx) if you actually need any of its features.

I currently run using ConEmu with a batch file to setup my preferred environment.  This is kept in my Dropbox folder so it remains synchronized between my computers.

Answer (score 1):

Console 2

http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Answer (score 0):

@Chirs
I think you need to clarify shell vs host(emulator).  To me it sounds like you need another interface to your existing shell that better supports copy and paste, not another shell that supports more/different features.

I second Pat's suggestion of Console2, it is a very good application and OSS to boot.

Answer (score 0):

I use the standard CMD.EXE shell but with a twist: an AutoHotKey script to support clipboard copy-paste as posted in: [Keyboard shortcut to paste clipboard content into command prompt window (Win XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp/133332)

Answer (score 0):

The Windows cmd shell, Cygwin Bash, and  msysgit Bash shells can be run within Emacs. [EmacsW32](http://ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) provides all three separately. You just have to set the bin directory to use either of the Bash shells. EmacsW32 also provides limited interactions between the Windows clipboard and the top item of the kill ring.

Answer (score 0):

**MinGW Shell** properly set up with:

- [right click menu entry](//github.com/svnpenn/home/blob/master/bash-prompt-here/add-bash-prompt-here.reg)
- [`~/.profile`](//github.com/svnpenn/home/blob/master/.profile) file

is well above anything else I have tried.

Comment: links are down..

Answer (score 0):

MinTTY on MinGW/MSYS is nice—nicer than on Cygwin because MinGW/MSYS is faster. Also, if you need `cmd.exe` behaviour, you can run `cmd.exe` inside of `mintty` easily.

See http://code.google.com/p/mintty/.