# CTRL+V from Windows command prompt?

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Keyboard shortcut to paste clipboard content into command prompt window (Win XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp)

Is there a keystroke command for pasting in the Windows command console? <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> does not work. The only thing that works is right click with the mouse and paste, but it is not efficient to transition from the keyboard to the mouse.

Comment: Not sure this really belongs on SO, but have you tried "Alt+Space E P" (navigates through the system menu to the edit->paste option).  A PITA, but better than the mouse.

Comment: And the above question is the first link on a Google search for windows command prompt paste shortcut.

Comment: On Windows 10, you can enable Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V in cmd.exe, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/31506358/395857

Comment: Man, I just searched for a similar thing. Here's my answer to save time for whoever else is interested: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40419159/843732 and btw, whoever marks these questions as duplicates, this is the first hit from Google.

Comment: Sadly the edit options don't exist on Win7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Keyboard shortcut to paste clipboard content into command prompt window (Win XP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp)

It's already been asked and answered there

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much for pointing me to this answer. I've been searching for this trick for a long time, this is fantastic. My brain thanks you as it will have to waste fewer cycles on transitioning from keyboard to mouse.

Comment: That's actually a horrid hack that really isn't a substitute. I wouldn't call this a duplicate.

Answer (score 13):

If you enable "Quick edit mode" then you can paste by right clicking with the mouse anywhere in the window - its not as quick as a shortcut key, but its quicker than the context menu.

To enable quick edit mode right click on the window border and select properties, on the resulting properties dialog make sure that "Quick edit mode" is selected and press OK:

[image: Screenshot of the properties dialog]

Comment: Mannnnnnnn! I was think about a CTRL+V, but this is much better so far!!! Genius!! Thanx!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell, merely right-clicking in the console window will paste whatever is in the clipboard. I know that's not quite what you are asking, but I still find it useful.