# How can I insert a backtick in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci, winghci

I'm trying out Haskell in GHCi on Windows. In the tutorial I'm following, a function name is enclosed in backticks: `` x `mod` 7 ``. However, I can't enter the character in GHCi.

The backtick character has ASCII value 096, but GHCI does not allow <kbd>Alt</kbd> + *number* to insert any character. Copying/pasting doesn't work either. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding the problem correctly, but the backtick character is typically located on a key immediately to the left of the "1" key on most keyboards: http://i.stack.imgur.com/TOn1U.png.

Comment: My version of GHCi accepts the backtick directly from my keyboard (although my keyboard isn't EN-US), and also accepts it from pasting. If you're using Windows, run GHCi on Powershell instead of Prompt to use Ctrl+V for pasting.

Comment: Have an Italian keyboard, has a \ left of 1, sorry

Comment: If you don't find another approach, you can always use GHCi through emacs, which has some other, more substantial, benefits.

Comment: This SuperUser question might help: [Italian keyboard: entering the tilde (~) and backtick (`) characters without changing keyboard layout](http://superuser.com/q/667622/320921).

Comment: Well, one thing to note is that backticks are never *necessary*. ``x `mod` 7`` is the same as `mod x 7`. Backticks are just a way to use a function in an infix manner. Also, these options don't sound particularly convenient, but here is some info on typing backticks on Italian keyboards: http://superuser.com/questions/598135/type-backtick-on-windows-italian-keyboard

Comment: @mephy Powershell works as Cmd, no ctrl/v and no backticks in GHCi. Outside GHCi those characters are insertednormally. It's GHCi that "eats" them, it seems

Comment: I know how to add ascii characters, that's not the question. It's about how to convince GHCi not to ignore them when I type them! GHCI seems to ignore quite a bit of what is typed in; all CTRL/*, all mouse clicks, all ALT/*** characters.

Comment: Really, once you've worked with Haskell in a properly configured emacs (a bit tricky to set up, I'll admit), even the pain of emacs will seem small compared to the benefits you get from near-real-time feedback from flycheck, HLint, etc. And mapping something to backtick will be pretty easy.

Comment: I would guess that this is more a problem of keyboard layouts + terminal encoding and not so much with `ghci` itself.

Comment: Everybody seems to think of it as a windows problem, it is NOT: it is GHCI that ignores a character typed correctly via the num-keypad. Guess I'll vave to follow David's advice and make changed in the tutorial examples. Thank you all.

Comment: @Martin Have you tried using WinGHCi? I think that still comes with the Haskell Platform and it has a GUI interface rather than using cmd.

Comment: Off on a tangent: Do Ctrl+Insert and Shift+Insert work for copy-pasting in PowerShell+GHCi? (I vaguely remember having done that in the past.)

Comment: Whether a command window supports copy&paste is independent of the shell. You can activate copy&paste (and other good stuff) in the command window's setting dialog, accessed from it's system menu: left-click on the window icon in the top-left corner of the window, select settings.

Comment: @Toxaris : It's NOT a windows problem, it's a GHCi problem

Comment: @Martin: Hmm. I can confirm that "paste by Ctrl-V" doesn't work in ghci. However, I just tried "paste by right mouse click" in a ghci running in a Windows command window and it works fine. ghci 7.8.3, Windows 8.1

Comment: Use Win7, right click does not show the usual menu Select, paste, etc. not in Cmd, not in Powershell

Comment: I guess the underlying problem is that ghci uses readline (or maybe some Haskell port of readline, I forgot), which defines its own CTRL-Whatever key combinations. Maybe readline can be configured to give you a key combination to insert a backtick?

Comment: Did you activate "quick edit mode" and "paste mode" in the command window's settings? I'm pretty sure they existed for at least a couple of Windows versions now.

Comment: Found WinGHCi after all, (it's not in the BIN map, so not on the PATH) and it works.  @David Young: formulate the answer and I'll mark it as correct

Comment: @Martin Well, the existing answer recommends using WinGHCi so I would suggest marking that as correct.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how send a backtick to ghci if your keyboard doesn't have it. But this little technical issue shouldn't stop you from trying out Haskell!

- You can program in Haskell without backticks by using `f a b` instead of `` a `f` b ``. In your example, `mod x 7`.
- You can set your keyboard layout to us-american for programming. While it takes some practice to find the keys with the wrong labels on the physical keyboard, it can be convenient to have `[`, `]`, `{` and `}` more accessible, and in your case, have the backtick at all.
- You can paste the backtick from the clipboard. (Activate "quick-edit mode" and "paste mode" from the command window's settings, and then use the right mouse button to paste).
- Maybe using a wrapper around the command window helps? I sometimes use Console2 and sometimes `M-x shell` in Emacs.
- Maybe WinGHCi helps? It supports copy and paste, at least.
- See Ørjan Johansen's answer for how to add a custom keybinding to ghci.

Good luck with Haskell!

Comment: The windows console doesn't support CTRL-V for pasting (in fact, it doesn't support any keyboard shortcut for pasting at all) - except on Windows 10, it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp/31506358#31506358

Comment: Really? How annoying. I use CTRL-V with the command prompt in my Windows console all the time, but I now realized it is provided by http://mridgers.github.io/clink/ not the vanilla console or command prompt. Sorry for my confusion.

Answer (score 6):

@Toxaris gave several suggestions in his answer, but in a comment he also mentioned the possibility of configuring GHCi's version of readline (which is called [`haskeline`](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline)). And indead it [allows custom keybindings](http://trac.haskell.org/haskeline/wiki/CustomKeyBindings). So I decided to test that out.

The documentation says to put the customizations in `~/.haskeline`, which is not a Windows path, but it presumably translates to `.haskeline` in whatever directory `System.Directory.getHomeDirectory` returns. (`vim` can also edit that path directly on Windows, but I only realized that afterwards.) So I put the following in `C:\Users\Ørjan\.haskeline`:

```
bind: meta-' `
```

Now I can get `` ` `` in GHCi by pressing `alt-'` !

Comment: Sorry to have indicated the correct answer already: YOURS is what I was looking for. Put it in what Windows calls HOMEPATH (c:\users\myname). Txs.

Comment: @Martin I think you can change which answer you accept. I'm happy that we solved your issue.