# Pasting in the Launch4j console

Tags: java, console, exe, paste, launch4j

I have googled for a while now, but no matter how I put the question, google just won't give me what I'm looking for (just watch how someone now will find the answer in 1 google search :D ). So I'm getting around to finally being able to convert my java code into .exe files using Launch4j, but one thing I noticed is I'm unable to paste into the console. I assumed since the console uses command prompt as it's base, it would have it's functions, but unfortunately not. This wouldn't be an issue most of the time, but when for example I want to enter a very long string of binary numbers, I'd rather not have to type it in. So if someone would tell me how (if at all possible) I can paste plain text into the console, I'd really appreciate it. Thank you!

update: ok, I've realized if I right click the title bar of the window and hover over "edit", I have access to the right click functions that would normally show up in a regular cmd window, so my original question is basically solved. However is it possible to compile the .exe such that I can just right click anywhere in the window rather than only the title bar? This simplicity is not for me, it's so the program is as user friendly as possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/131969

Comment: Is this question just about the normal cmd console, or is there a special Launch4j console?

Comment: normal cmd console that shows up when you launch the .exe file that the Launch4j program compiles from the .jar file.