# Doesn't works CTRL+V in PyAutoGUI, Python 3 on Windows

Tags: python, module, keyboard, hotkeys, emulation

I have the latest version of Python 3 and PyAutoGUI module on Windows 7 x64. Hotkeys like <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F4</kbd>, <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ESC</kbd> works pretty well, but, from what I noticed, doesn't works <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> at all!

Comment: I noticed, that all hotkeys, containing letters, doesn't works, e. g. CTRL+N.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keyboard shortcut to paste clipboard content into command prompt window (Win XP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp)

Comment: [Keyboard shortcut to paste clipboard content into command prompt window (Win XP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp) This has been asked and answered there.

Answer (score 2):

choose "EN" default keyboard layout in your OS

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using CTRL + **SHFT** + C and CTRL + **SHFT** + V?
If not, those should work. When I was copying from the terminal, it worked to do CTRL SHFT C.