# How to paste text in DEV C++ command prompt using hotkeys?

Tags: c++, hotkeys

I want to copy+paste text in dev c++ command prompt using ctrl+v. I searched for the ways to do it online but could not find the solution, some answers even suggest that it is impossible, but I know for sure that it is possible because I did it a couple of years ago.
[image: shor]

Comment: Will [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/16313/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-in-windows-command-prompt/16318) solve your problem?

Comment: have you tried copying then right clicking in the console?

Comment: @Liang yes I've tried it, it's not working.

Comment: @Valerii Boldakov Thanks. So I assume it is impossible in Windows versions before 10?

Comment: @ArchilZhvania [there is the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131955/keyboard-shortcut-to-paste-clipboard-content-into-command-prompt-window-win-xp/133332) with some scripting.