# Is there a better Windows command-line shell?

Tags: windows, shell, cmd

CMD.EXE is posing lots of problems for me.  I have Cygwin installed and use bash regularly, and I also have the mingwin bash shell that comes with mSysGit, but sometimes I really do need to run things from the Windows shell.

Is there a replacement for the Windows shell that:

- has a persistent command-line history, available in my next session after I close a session? (as in bash HISTFILE)
- remembers what directory I was just in so that I can toggle between two directories? (as in bash cd -)

(Or is there a way to enable these features in CMD.EXE?)

I see some has asked about [a better windows shell before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724/better-windows-command-line-shells), but they were asking about cut and paste which is lower in priority for me at this point.  It's not the console that's killing me, it's the command-line interpreter.

Comment: Powershell is not an answer to my question.  As I noted in comments to Seb's answer, Powershell does not have persistent command-line history.  I'm not asking for something that's better in general, I'm asking for something with specific requirements.  Removed powershell tag since this isn't a powershell question.

Comment: I use [ConEmu](http://www.fosshub.com/ConEmu.html), really nice command line replacement.

Comment: @jamescampbell Not the console, the shell.  I use ConEmu, too, but it's a console, not a shell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've always liked 4NT (haven't used it for a while now).

It's an enhanced command interpreter for windows, and it's mostly backwards compatible (meaning you can run normal windows batchfiles). The only reason not to use it is that it doesn't ship with Windows like the default command.exe does.

Compared to the default windows commandline interpreter, it has better flow control mechanisms. All standard windows commandline tools are available, but with extra options and parameters.

Basically it's what CMD.exe should've been.

**Update**: looks like it's not called 4NT anymore, but TakeCommand:
http://jpsoft.com/products.htm

Comment: Probably the free TCC/LE from http://jpsoft.com/products.htm is sufficient too, it claims to have shell history as well.

Answer (score 25):

Microsoft's just released [Powershell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx). (about 2 years ago)

I've already downloaded it; didn't try it much, but seems a nice tool.

Comment: This appears to be as close as Powershell gets to persistent history: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/topics/msh/cmdlets/add-history.mspx

Comment: "just released"? it's been available for more than 2 years!!

Comment: Maybe he meant PowerShell 2, CTP 3 was released in December.  I'm looking forward to V2.

Comment: I meant stable version 1.0! :)

Comment: I'm happy to see the buffer size is bigger :) (ability to scroll up more lines).

Comment: This answer is simply off topic and gives no help

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Powershell too. It's a great, linux shell-like but object oriented, extensible framework. Cool not for just system administrators but for developers too (build process etc.). Powershell rocks bash or other linux competitors:)

Main adventages:

- **Extensible** with .NET languages
- Use of **.NET objects** (DateTime, File etc.)
- Easy and clear syntax
- Remoting
- **Debug**
- Steppable pipelines
- ...

More from here:

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/default.aspx

http://windowsteamblog.com/blogs/windowsvista/archive/2006/11/14/it-forum-day-one-windows-vista-and-windows-powershell.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/powershell/archive/2007/11/06/what-s-new-in-ctp-of-powershell-2-0.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Another brilliant solution is 'Clink' which enhances CMD.exe with persistent history and many more BASH-like features. Just install it and then open CMD as normal.
See: http://code.google.com/p/clink/

Or if you really want 'cd -' to work taking you to the previous directory then install 'TCC/LE' free version from http://jpsoft.com as mentioned by Wouter and Peter.

Comment: clink seems to be the best out there...

Answer (score 5):

[PyCmd](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/) fits both of your requirements! And it's built on top of cmd.exe...

1. the command history is persistent across PyCmd sessions
2. history of recently visited directories (Alt-Left/Right/D on empty line)

Here you have the list of features http://sourceforge.net/projects/pycmd/files/pycmd/0.8/

Answer (score 4):

try console2:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/

i like it

Comment: Is that usable by now? I took a look at it a while ago and it was buggy as hell ...

Comment: Doesn't address any of the problems I have.  As I said, I'm not looking for a better console; I'm looking for a better shell.

Comment: console2 is just UI front-end. Crap in crap out!, a la command prompt

Comment: I like the tabs, but I still can't figure out how to select and copy text from it. If it actually has that feature they still fail for making it so hard to figure out.

Comment: For help configuring console2: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/Console2ABetterWindowsCommandPrompt.aspx

Answer (score 2):

[PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx), I would say. It is Microsoft's new official shell for command line administration.

I use it for development tasks myself, and like it. It gives you the flexibility to interact with the .NET framework classes directly on the command line, which can be very powerful.

Answer (score 2):

Others have mentioned Powershell and 4NT already, both are much better solutions than `CMD` and all its arcane syntax, lack of documentation and often-surprising inability to do almost any task you might want to use it for :)

- 4NT is now part of `Take Command` GUI file-management suite, but the owners have made just the shell part available on its own, it's called TCC/LE now and is also now free! For most people I'd say to use this - it's the easiest learning curve by being having a mostly compatible syntax to `CMD`, having lots of resources online and being capable of doing say 80% of file system tasks perfectly.

  [TCC/LE download](http://jpsoft.com/tccle-cmd-replacement.html)
- For people with more obscure needs, doing lots of administration, or want more flexibility, try Powershell - it's a steep initial learning curve, but it's internally very consistent and once you've figured out the basics you can access and operate on 99.9% of everything Windows handles using the same set of tools and methods, even executing it across a network on other machines. Even learning the basics (sort, select, % and ?) is better than `CMD` already...

  [PowerShell Owner's Manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee221100.aspx)

  [PowerShell Examples](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/powershellexamples.php)
- If you're more technically inclined then I'd consider IPython - at the core it's a console for writing and executing Python code, but it also acts as a shell (and task management system) very handily - it has bookmarks, aliases, tab completion of code/files, can mix code and shell commands e.g. `files=!dir *.txt` saves the output of `dir *.txt`, configurable logging of input and/or outputs, can repeat blocks of past commands, export them or create macros, and has extensions which can customise it more.

  [IPython as a shell](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/shell.html)

  Definitely not for the faint of heart, but a very powerful environment if you know Python!

Answer (score 1):

pushd and popd can be used to navigate to and from directories.

c:>pushd windows
c:\Windows>popd
c:\

Comment: Been using that, but it won't work to toggle.

Answer (score 1):

PowerShell works quite well when you do your things in PowerShell way. For example when you want to mess around with .NET apps and Windows files. It works great for scripting as the syntax is a lot nicer than in Bash...

But when you want to work with some typical UNIX apps, then you can easily get into trouble when PowerShell converts all your LF line endings to CRLF (and don't even think about piping binary files).

Just my experience.

Answer (score 0):

Then there's the PowerShell!  Haven't tried it, but I've heard many nice things about it.

Answer (score -2):

I use cygwin. It's a posix implementation for Windows. So, you can run unix like programs on windows. The default terminal is bash, which is much more advanced than windows cmd.

Comment: I use Cygwin, too, as I noted in my original question. ;)  But it doesn't fit all the needs for an enhanced cmd.exe, although it is certainly superior.  It's just that it's sometimes inferior at being like Windows' original inferior shell.